# Fix arrow keys displaying A, B, C, D in vi (not in vim)

Tags: key-bindings, original-vi

I know that in vim I can add

```
set nocompatible
```

in `.vimrc` to avoid that arrow keys display A, B, C, D in insert mode.

But I'm using vi *Version 4.0 (gritter) 12/25/06*.

How can I obtain the same behavior?

**== EDIT == (1)**

I'm using the [vi version from Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/vi/) which is built from this [CVS repository](http://ex-vi.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ex-vi/ex-vi/) (last commit 24 February 2007) with the following command:

```
make PREFIX=/usr LIBEXECDIR=/usr/lib/ex PRESERVEDIR=/var/lib/ex \
TERMLIB=ncurses FEATURES="-DCHDIR -DFASTTAG -DUCVISUAL -DMB -DBIT8"
```

and with theses three patches: [fix-tubesize-short-overflow.patch](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/fix-tubesize-short-overflow.patch?h=packages/vi), [navkeys.patch](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/navkeys.patch?h=packages/vi) and [preserve-dir.patch](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/preserve-dir.patch?h=packages/vi).

**== EDIT (2)==**

The problems happens in [LXTerminal 0.2.0](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/lxterminal/), [Termite 10-1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Termite), [Tilda 1.2.4-1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tilda), [Terminator 0.98-1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Terminator) and [xterm 320-2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm) but not in [urxvt v9.21](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode)  nor in the Linux virtual consoles.

**== EDIT (3)==**

According to the [Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/terminfo.html) left-arrow, down-arrow, right-arrow, up-arrow correspond to respectively the following capname : `kcub1`, `kcud1`, `kcuf1` and `kcuu1`. Comparing terminfo entries from `xterm` and `rxvt-unicode-256color` for these capterms gives:

```
$ infocmp xterm rxvt-unicode-256color | grep -E 'kcuf1|kcub1|kcud1|kcuu1'

kcub1: '\EOD', '\E[D'.
kcud1: '\EOB', '\E[B'.
kcuf1: '\EOC', '\E[C'.
kcuu1: '\EOA', '\E[A'.
```

Modifying the xterm terminfo entry by substituing `'\EOD'`, `'\EOB'`, `'\EOC'`, `'\EOA'`  by `'\E[D'`, `'\E[B'`, `'\E[C'`, `'\E[A'` should solve the problem but is it a good idea? Maybe it will break other programs arrow keys usage?

Comment: I think this is caused by vi(m) <-> terminal interaction, so you can also try some terminal-related workarounds/configuration.

Comment: Which $TERM do you suggest, for this problem?

Comment: Translation of what @VanLaser said above: your entry for the current `TERM` in the `termcap` or `terminfo` databases is out of synch with the codes produced by the keyboard.  The solution is not to change the `TERM`, but to find out if your `vi` is linked against `termcap` or `terminfo`, find the keycodes emitted by the keyboard, and fix the corresponding database accordingly.  Complaining to the sysadmin might work, too.

Comment: Did I say all that? Sometimes I amaze myself :) (of course, all I knew was that it's terminal related).

Comment: This version of vi is built with ncurses, it should then use `terminfo`.

Comment: Did you see [these tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell)? Maybe something of them can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an alias that sets your `$TERM` variable

```
alias vi='TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color vi'
```

Add that to your shell's rc file and it should be defined for every terminal you launch.

Comment: On my system this will just make Vi leave insert mode (which is probably better than having it print garbage, but still doesn't quite fix the issue).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes such behaviour can result from unusual key mappings setup in your `.vimrc` - so for example if you have something that maps two <kbd>ESC</kbd> key presses:

```
nmap <Esc><Esc> some_command_sequence
```

Then it can lead to vim malfunctioning with the arrow keys.

Comment: The configuration described by the OP is quite specific, and it displays the behaviour without such a mapping being in place. (I've tested it.)

Answer (score 0):

The true fix is to use Command mode for movement, not Insert mode.
The behavior you are seeing is not a bug, but proper vi/POSIX behavior.
You are trying to *change* something you are telling it to do on purpose.

You are telling vi to *Insert* the characters represented by the arrow keys, so it does.

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get back into Command mode and then you can probably use the arrow keys as desired, including the count functions.
Using a modal editor like vi as if it is Windows notepad (mode-less) will never teach you the power and flexibility of vi.

If you don't want to learn vi, then maybe consider nano or mg / emacs.
They are mode-less also.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The core of the answer is great: use Normal mode to move around. I think it could do without all the scare-quotes/"you're doing it wrong" attitude. It's fine to suggest there are better ways, but consider how you word it. Just my 2 cents.