# Weird arrow key behaviour in fzf.vim terminal mode

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-fzf

My `.vimrc` contains junegunn's [implementation](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples-(vim)#simple-mru-search) of Most Recently Used FZF search:

```
nmap <Leader><Leader> :FZFMru<CR>

command! FZFMru call fzf#run({
\  'source':  v:oldfiles,
\  'sink':    'e',
\  'options': '-m -x +s',
\  'down':    '40%'})
```

Recently, while this FZF window is open, I find the up and down keys behave strangely. In normal mode I hit `<Leader><Leader>`, and the FZF windows opens. Hitting `<Up>`, `<Down>`, `<Left>` or `<Right>` switches me into insert mode and types respectively A, B, C or D (upper case). Looking at `:map` I don't see that these keys are mapped to anything, in any mode.

What is going on?

Update: it seems like this is connected to the `fzf.vim` plugin's using terminal mode - in the floating terminal the arrow keys are mapped to these sequences:

```
up - "\027[A"
down - "\027[B"
left - "\027[D"
right - "\027[C"
```

(ie  vi-compatible mode, even though within my main Vim session I use `set nocompatible` and this isn't an issue.) There is a GitHub discussion [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/16). However, it's  very hard to figure out under which conditions this occurs.

Comment: I don’t remember what key octal 27 is off the top of my head, but have you mapped the escape key at all?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble no, I haven't

Comment: (turns out I had...  )

Comment: @filbranden good idea, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by a change I'd made in my `.vimrc`, a mapping to let me `<Esc>` to exit terminal mode `tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>:bd!<CR>`, identical to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2216). One solution is to map double escape, eg `tnoremap <Esc><Esc> <c-\><c-n>`.

Explanation: the issue seems to be that: a) fzf.vim uses **terminal mode**, which I rarely use; b) I added a terminal-mode modification which only showed up when using this plugin; c) apparently when `<Esc>` is mapped, Vim temporarily interprets it as a literal escape sequence, so that the arrow keys send ^[OA, etc., which goes from terminal mode back to normal mode, adds a new line and types A. (All of this is explained in many other places, such as [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14446/26984).)